# Offline Google Maps in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, offline

I am looking for Offline Google Maps in iOS (Objective c).

Is there any way to download the Map into the App when user is connected to internet, and show the downloaded map when user is offline and using the App ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline maps SDK for Android and iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239157/offline-maps-sdk-for-android-and-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about it but I have heard some once talking about the same thing and using openstreetmaps instead of Google Maps.

OpenStreetMaps: http://www.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: this isn´t really an answer to the question more an advice and should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I would have made a comment if I had enough reputation, I can only comment my own stuff

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Google Maps doesn't implement that feature on its iOS Framework yet. But there are other Frameworks, such as Skobbler or Nutiteq that provide what you need.

Answer (score -3):

It is quite easy to use Google maps as the offline mode you just need to download the map for the particular location you need to visit offline, later you can access that map anytime. I recommend you to see complete tutorial with screenshots [here](https://www.madestuffeasy.com/download-google-maps-offline-navigation-on-android-or-iphone/).

Follow some below steps:

- 1: Open google maps.
- 2: Navigate to the menu, and select offline area.
- 3: Select the area you want to use as area as an offline map.
- 4: Now tap download.

You can access this map in future for one month after which it will ask for updates.